How to see the participant who makes the call in Microsoft Teams with the graft api?
Good communities, I am trying to identify the participant who makes the call and the participant who receives it, I am not talking about a meeting but one on one.
Thanks!
i receved all Participant but i do see who doin the call

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Currently it is not possible to get the details of who initiated the call. To better achieve your requirements, we recommend submitting this feature request through the [Teams Feedback Portal](Microsoft Teams · Community). This is the best way to ensure your idea is considered for future updates.
We appreciate your input and encourage you to share any additional thoughts!

I found in the api Graph of Microsoft
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{callchainid}
The response give me a initiator of call into organize_v2 the name of initiator
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/callRecords/$entity",
"version": 1,
"type": "peerToPeer",
"modalities": [
"audio"
],
"lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-02-25T19:00:24.582757Z",
"startDateTime": "2020-02-25T18:52:21.2169889Z",
"endDateTime": "2020-02-25T18:52:46.7640013Z",
"id": "e523d2ed-2966-4b6b-925b-754a88034cc5",
"organizer_v2@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/callRecords('e523d2ed-2966-4b6b-925b-754a88034cc5')/organizer_v2/$entity",
"organizer_v2": {
"id": "821809f5-0000-0000-0000-3b5136c0e777",
"identity": {
"user": {
"id": "821809f5-0000-0000-0000-3b5136c0e777",
"displayName": "Abbie Wilkins",
"tenantId": "dc368399-474c-4d40-900c-6265431fd81f"
}
}
},
"participants_v2@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#communications/callRecords('e523d2ed-2966-4b6b-925b-754a88034cc5')/participants_v2/$entity"
}`
Thanks everyone!

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
